# How to design a circular buffer that is unix domain sockets based?

Tags: file, embedded, ipc, unix-socket, circular-buffer

I want to make a circular buffer that can be interacted with by two languages, C and Javascript.
This will be deployed on an embedded device and contain only one producer and one consumer:

This is how I thought to implement circular buffer components:

head: `/tmp/head`

tail: `/tmp/tail`

buffer: `/tmp/b1`, `/tmp/b2`, `/tmp/b3` ... `/tmp/bn`

1. Is this a valid approach or is it overcomplicated/missing a point?

It just seems I would have to iterate over non-blocking file descriptors based on head/tail data gotten from another thread, I can't quite put my finger on it but it seems overcomplicated.

2. Is this really best achieved with sockets, or would other mechanism be more suitable (pipes/files/posix)?
3. Any other pitfalls in my assumptions or any other criticism?

Any articles/tutorials on that area/topic would I'd love to read them, I struggled slightly as I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase what I'm looking for and satisfy search algorithm to return something useful.

Thanks for your help!